# How to send few parameters via POST method?

Tags: php, http, post, get

I want to send parameters as Key-Value via POST. With GET method it easy to make:

> myDomain.com?**a=3&b=2&c=1**

But how to make same request via POST method (I dont want to send all data as String with some delimiter and then parse this String on server via `Split()` method)?

Comment: Send from where? From a html-page a simple <form action="whatever" method="post"> will do. Or do you want to send it from some proxy php page or by Ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional format is the same. It just appears in the HTTP request body instead of as part of the URI. Whatever library you use to parse the query string should handle x-www-form-urlencoded data just as easily.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

a=3&b=2&c=1
```

Comment: changing Header's "Content Type" to  application/x-www-form-urlencoded is necessary?

Comment: @Hello — "changing"? There isn't a default, and if you have a message body you "SHOULD" have a content-type header ("SHOULD" means "Must unless you have a damn good reason, which you won't")

Answer (score 0):

You should use either form method = POST or ajax.

Jquery ajax is easier. Just google it. (if you want it that way).

P.s. You can't send post parameters via url.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to send POST data is from an html form:

```
<FORM action="http://somesite.com/somescript.php" method="post">
   <P>
   <LABEL for="firstname">First name: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" id="firstname"><BR>
   <LABEL for="lastname">Last name: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" id="lastname"><BR>
   <LABEL for="email">email: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" id="email"><BR>
   <INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Male"> Male<BR>
   <INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Female"> Female<BR>
   <INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
   </P>
</FORM>
```

Then process the $_POST vars similar to how you would with $_GET vars in PHP.